# Integrating Existing Java Project with Groovy

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, groovy

I have my Existing JAVA project.

I have to run a Groovy script through a Java file from this project.

I'm Using Groovy Grails Tool Suite (GGTS).

1. Have changed the JAVA project nature to Groovy nature from the IDE option
2. Have externally included groovy-all.2.0.7.jar in ANT/lib too.

Source Code has following imports:

```
import groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader;
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import groovy.lang.MetaMethod;
```

Now I am trying to build it using build.xml (ANT) configuration.

BUILD.xml

```
<taskdef name="groovyc" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc">
  <classpath refid="groovy.classpath" />
</taskdef>
<target name="compile.groovy" description="Compile both groovy&Java"depends="init">
  <groovyc srcdir="src" destdir="bin/classes">
    <classpath refid="groovy.classpath" />
    <javac debug="on" deprecation="true" />
  </groovyc>
</target>
```

But I get the following error :

```
package groovy.lang does not exist [javac] import groovy.lang.*;
```

Please assist as to why the groovy-all-2.0.7.jar is not recognised!!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried removing `groovy-all` from your `ant/lib` directory, adding it to a `lib` directory under your project, and then doing:

```
<path id="groovy.all.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
<taskdef name="groovyc" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc"  classpathref="groovy.all.classpath"/>
```

Comment: tried with your suggestion but no luck :-(. My build.xml have jar build for its regular java project .what snippet u shared.. i did append and tried